# Are Mongo Charts possible in Compass Client?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to use Google charts in MongoDB Compass? I have an AWS version, but can I use charts locally on the client?

Comment: Do you mean MongoDB Compass or MongoDB Charts?

Comment: MongoDB compass